# Postgres regex stop creating double space

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select regexp_replace('john (junior) jones','\([^)]*\)','','g');
  regexp_replace  
------------------
 john  jones
```

As you can see, this query removes the values in brackets but it results in a double space remaining.

Is there an easy way around this?

So far I have this, which works to an extent:

```
select regexp_replace((regexp_replace('john (junior) jones','\([^)]*\)','','g')),'\s','');
  regexp_replace  
------------------
 john jones
```

The above works but not when I pass through something like this:

```
select regexp_replace((regexp_replace('john (junior) jones (hughes) smith','\([^)]*\)','','g')),'\s','');
   regexp_replace    
---------------------
 john jones  smith
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
          'john (junior) jones (hughes) smith',
          ' *\([^)]*\) *',
          ' ',
          'g'
       );

  regexp_replace  
══════════════════
 john jones smith
(1 row)
```

To explain the regular expression:

- an arbitrary number of spaces, followed by an opening parenthesis ( `*\(`)
- an arbitrary number of characters that are not a closing parenthesis (`[^)]*`)
- a closing parenthesis and arbitrarily many spaces (`\) *`)

That is replaced with a single space.

Comment: Thanks! That is much closer to what I want - the only issue is if the brackets are at the start/end I am left with a trailing/leading space. Is it best to just wrap this up in a trim as a result?

Comment: Yes, perhaps that is a simpler solution than coming up with a more complicated expression.